# PHP - Simple ajax to send query to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Forgive my ignorance, but I can't figure out how to do a simple ajax request in PHP. I understand the principles of client-server communication in other languages/libraries, but PHP eludes me for some reason.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Send a request from here, utilizing jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploadAll', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ExamplePhpFile.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {query:'INSERT INTO Assets SELECT * FROM Uploads'},
        success: function(respose){
            console.log("POST successful");
        }
    });
});
```

**Get the query string in the data attribute here:**

```
if(isset($_POST{'data'})) {
    $query = $_POST['data'];
    foreach($query as $value) {
        echo 'here is your crap: '.$value;
    }
}
```

Then I will use the passed query in another function to run an action on the server (this part works). Obviously I have something wrong, as the **$_POST['data']** bit doesn't return a value. And monitoring **$_POST** by itself just gives me an array object (JSON_encode() doesn't do the trick on that either)

Can anyone offer me guidance, and save me some hair pulling? :)

Comment: Also it is a **REALLY** bad security vulnerability to send SQL statements across web requests.

Comment: I forgot them in the post, they're there in the file. I'll edit to reflect :)

Comment: Also your parameters will not have `data` as a key.  It will have `query` as a key.  `$_POST['query']`

Comment: Turns out you can actually use the `{}` as in `isset($post{'data'})` ... lol who  knew.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix As I just pointed out, `data` will not be a key in the `$_POST` associative array

Comment: @Taplar I can see the security problems with that, and don't plan on doing it that way in prod, I just have it there so I can figure this out. Also, echoing $_POST['query'] gets me a blank object :/

Comment: @Taplar - that's true as it's `$_POST['query']` I was just looking at the `{}` either I forgot or didn't realize they actually work for accessing an array, probably not the best idea to use it for readability... but who knew lol  I probably forgot more PHP then some people know. ha ha

Comment: @Jensen010 open your developer tools, go to the network console and then make your request happen.  Find your request and look at it's request content.  Verify that your query key and expected value is in there.

Comment: @Taplar, the query key/value shows in the form data within the http headers, so it looks like it's getting sent, just not interpreted?

Comment: And it is indeed a POST request in the network logs?

Comment: Yes, with a status code of 200

Comment: Ok, so that's weird.  Try changing the value for the moment to something else like `{query: 'test'}` or `{thing:'INSERT INTO Assets SELECT * FROM Uploads'}` and see if anything changes.

Comment: Changed keys and values, both are reflected in the headers, but nothing on the server. I don't get it, I just need to send a string to a server file, haha

Comment: Yeah, i'm not entirely sure where to suggest going from here.  If you see the key value in your network request, that shows that the ajax request is sending the data.  I'm not sure why you are not seeing anything on your PHP side.  You could try generating the request in a REST Client and see if the issue persists, thus removing javascript/ajax from the equation.

Comment: I'll keep messing with it, i'm sure there's a simple solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing your data key as `query` and using `$_POST['data']` so how it will work replace like `$_POST['data']` to `$_POST['query']` it will work.

Comment: hmmm, I tried that, and when I echo it, i get nothing :(

Comment: Show us var_dump($_POST) output

Comment: its empty? this confuses me

Comment: Try echoing `file_get_contents('php://input')` to see what the raw HTTP request body is. Might be some clues in there.

Comment: That's empty too, something appears to be wrong with the client side of things?

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a valid JSON object back

```
if(isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $data = [];
    $x = 0;
    foreach($query as $value) {
        $data[$x] = 'here is your crap: '.$value;
        $x++;
    }
    print(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: What difference do you think that makes? He clearly said he is not getting a response, it's because he's not returning a valid JSON object. Maybe read the actual question and the response before downvoting everyone? Just a thought

Comment: He also clearly said his queries work, it's the response to the AJAX call he isn't getting.

Comment: What part of the issue do you think it isn't addressing? He wants to know how to get a response from the server when the AJAX call is done.

Comment: Now I see where you were going with that. Sorry, long day.